# What is the size of template class in c++?

Tags: c++11, templates

The output of the below code is 16. Why so? even without initializing with the length of array of the class the size is 16 and with initializing the length with the 2nd constructor,  it is the same size i.e. 16. Any explanation?

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class array1{
    T * arr;
    int l;
    public:
    array1(){
        arr = 0; l=0;
        }
    array1(int x){
        l = x;
        arr = new T[l];
    }
    ~array1(){
        delete[] arr;
        }
    void display(){
        cout << "array1 is :"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
array1<int> a1;
cout << "size of int arr is " << sizeof(a1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates, you'll get the same thing with a normal class.

Comment: Can you share with us your assumptions about why it should be something other than 16?

Comment: What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of [Data Structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). In your system it is being aligned to 8 bytes word. Print the `sizeof(T*)` and `sizeof(int)` it will output `8` and `4` respectively in the constructor of `array` class. But when output together it takes 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your integer and pointer types are both 8 bytes/64 bits. Also, just a heads up, `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, meaning that even if an object of your type allocates memory on the heap with the `operator new[]`, `sizeof` will still return 16 bytes for any object of type `array1`.

Additionally, no matter what type you have for `T`, `sizeof(array1<T>)` will always be 16 bytes. (I am making the assumption that you are not compiling on an atypical target.)

Answer (score 0):

Your class has two member variables. A pointer and an int. I suspect that both are eight bytes in size for your platform.

If so, then: 8 + 8 = 16.

(Your class has no virtual methods -- so no vtable overhead).

Comment: Since you tagged this question with C++11 you can also verify this: `cout << "Sizeof arr, l is " << sizeof a1.arr << " + " << sizeof a1.l << endl;`